# How do i export workflow rule criteria?

Tags: workflow, eclipse

How do i export workflow rule criteria, can anyone suggest me please.

I am trying to export it from my own org(Eclipse IDE doesnt seems to be working for me).

Is there any other way i can export workflows.

Thanks

Comment: You can use ant -- http://salesforce-stuff.blogspot.nl/2011/10/using-ant-to-retrieve-metadata-of.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind messing with APIs, you can use the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) (which is what the Force IDE uses behind the scenes). That's the most direct one, but it has a learning curve if you've never done it.

On the other hand, there are other tools. You have Joe Ferraro's [Mavensmate](http://mavensmate.com) for Sublime, which allows you to download Metadata too, or native tools from the AppExchange, like [Copado](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir0s738cvUAhVGXRQKHYCaBwAQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fappexchange.salesforce.com%2FlistingDetail%3FlistingId%3Da0N3000000B3dgGEAR&usg=AFQjCNEnFnNXriFjZqRQgz8fLeCPX32YLA).

I hope it was useful!